# Почему новые пользователи не могут подключиться через SFTP?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp

Взял бесплатную машину у Oracle и поставил туда Ubuntu. По дефолту там тебе выдают пользователя Ubuntu и пару ключей (public и private key). Я отключил PubkeyAuthentication и на данный момент у меня sshd_config выглядит вот так

```
PermitRootLogin yes

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftpusers
ChrootDirectory %h
ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /public_html -u 0007
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

Я плохо знаю linux, поэтому все мои действия - это копипасты с других вопросов. Я создаю пользователя вот таким образом:

```
addgroup --system sftpusers
useradd -d /var/www/test -s /bin/false -g sftpusers useruser
passwd useruser
usermod -a -G sftpusers www-data
chown -R www-data:sftpusers /var/www/test/public_html
chmod -R 770 /var/www/test/public_html
```

и при подключении через filezilla sftp я получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Статус: Using username "useruser". 
Команда:    Pass: ********
Ошибка: FATAL ERROR: Network error: Software caused connection abort
Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу
```

Подключиться к ssh через putty на пользователя useruser у меня тоже не выходит. Хотя на пользователя Ubuntu и root я могу подключиться. Подскажите пожалуйста, как выяснить в чём причина и какую команду нужно ввести, чтобы всё начало работать?

Comment: Выхлоп `grep useruser /etc/group` в студию.